# Are snapshots generated for each sub query inside a Postgres READ_COMMITTED transaction?

Tags: postgresql, transaction, snapshot, mvcc

From what I understand - in a READ_COMMITTED Postgres transaction “the transaction obtains a snapshot whenever an SQL command is executed” [source](http://www.interdb.jp/pg/pgsql05.html). Does this mean a snapshot will be obtained for each sub query in a nested query? Does the use of CTEs in place of sub queries affect this behavior?

Comment: No, it's a single snapshot for the whole (top-level) query. CTEs don't change that, it's still a single query.

Comment: Great, thanks! Want to make that an answer?

Answer (score 1):

The snapshot 'created' is per statement regardless of whether that statement contains subqueries or not. From the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/transaction-iso.html):

> ... This level is different from Read Committed in that a query in a repeatable read transaction sees a snapshot as of the start of the first non-transaction-control statement in the transaction, not as of the start of the current statement within the transaction.